# Why doesn't my script work, but I can manually INSERT into mysql?

Tags: python, mysql, database

```
conn = MySQLdb.connect(host='db1', user='user', passwd='pass', db='db', port=3306)
cursor = conn.cursor()

count = int(sys.argv[1])
x = 0
while x < count:
    x += 1
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO auth_group(name) VALUES(%s)", (str(x)))
    #if I change %s to 'kkkk', it doesn't work either.

    print str(x) + ' / ' + str(count)
print 'done'
```

However...if I go into "mysql -uuser -ppass db", it works:

```
mysql > INSERT INTO auth_group(name) VALUES('kkkkk');
```

I don't know if this could be a problem...but I was having a replication issue earlier.

I would like to INSERT 99999 rows into the database. But it's empty.

```
mysql> select * from auth_group;
Empty set (0.33 sec)
```

Comment: Would you mind telling us, how exactly it doesn't work?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If there's no particular error message (in other words, it seems to work, but the insert doesn't stick), make sure you commit() after the statement:

```
conn.commit()
```

Comment: I don't know what you mean by this comment, but I most strongly suggest NOT turning autocommit on, unless you are absolutely sure, that you want it (hint: you don't). Transactions are there for a reason. Use them.

Answer (score 3):

You have to commit (by issuing a `conn.commit()`), because autocommit is off by default (and rightfully so).

Answer (score 1):

If it happens that none of your data get stored even after commiting, have a look at my answer to this issue: [pymysql callproc() appears to affect subsequent selects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8218870/pymysql-callproc-appears-to-affect-subsequent-selects/8878775#8878775)

The basic idea there is to use executemany() instead of execute() to get the data stored.
(pymysql 0.5 for Python 3.2).

A little later I found out that the actual problem is that exit() is executed too fast and because of that, the data don't get stored in the database.

So, finally the problem seems to be fixed with:

```
[…]
cur.execute("insert into …")
import time
time.sleep(2)

cur.close()
conn.close()
time.sleep(2)
exit()
```

It works!