# pymysql callproc() appears to affect subsequent selects

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

I'm attempting to transition a code base from using MySQLdb to pymysql.  I'm encountering the following problem and wonder if anyone has seen something similar.

In a nutshell, if I call a stored procedure through the pymysql cursor callproc() method a subsequent 'select' call through the execute() method using the same or a different cursor returns incorrect results.   I see the same results for Python 2.7.2 and Python 3.2.2

Is the callproc() method locking up the server somehow?   Code is shown below:

```
conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', user='me', passwd='pwd',db='mydb')

curr = conn.cursor()

rargs = curr.callproc("getInputVar", (args,))
resultSet = curr.fetchone()
print("Result set   : {0}".format(resultSet))

# curr.close()
#
# curr = conn.cursor()

curr.execute('select * from my_table')
resultSet = curr.fetchall()
print("Result set len : {0}".format(len(resultSet)))        

curr.close()
conn.close()
```

I can uncomment the close() and cursor creation calls above but this doesn't change the result.   If I comment out the callproc() invocation the select statement works just fine.

Comment: If I change the name of the table in the select statement no exception is generated, so it doesn't seem like this request even got to the database server.   If I completely close the connection and re-open it, everything works fine, but I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem with (committed) INSERT statements not appearing in the database. PyMySQL 0.5 für Python 3.2 and MySQL Community Server 5.5.19.

I found the solution for me: instead of using the execute() method, I used the executemany method, explained in the module reference on 
http://code.google.com/p/pymssql/wiki/PymssqlModuleReference
There is also a link to examples.

**Update**
A little later, today, I found out that this is not yet the full solution.
A too fast exit() at the end of the python script makes the data getting lost in the database. 
So, I added a time.sleep() before closing the connection and before exit()ing the script, and finally all the data appeared!
(I also switched to using a myisam table)

```
import pymysql
conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', user='root', passwd='', db='mydb', charset='utf8')
conn.autocommit(True)
cur = conn.cursor()

# CREATE tables (SQL statements generated by MySQL workbench, and exported with Menu -> Database -> Forward Engineer)
cur.execute("""
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL';

DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS `mydb` ;
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `mydb` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci ;
USE `mydb` ;
# […]

SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;

""")

# Fill lookup tables:

cur.executemany("insert into mydb.number(tagname,name,shortform) values (%s, %s, %s)", [('ЕД','singular','sg'), ('МН','plural','p')] )
cur.executemany("insert into mydb.person(tagname,name,shortform) values (%s, %s, %s)", [('1-Л','first','1st'), ('2-Л','second','2nd'), ('3-Л','third','3rd')] )
cur.executemany("insert into mydb.pos(tagname,name,shortform) values (%s, %s, %s)", [('S','noun','s'), ('A','adjective','a'), ('ADV','adverb','adv'), ('NUM','numeral','num'), ('PR','preposition','pr'), ('COM','composite','com'), ('CONJ','conjunction','conj'), ('PART','particle','part'), ('P','word-clause','p'), ('INTJ','interjection','intj'), ('NID','foreign-named-entity','nid'), ('V','verb','v')] )
#[…]

import time
time.sleep(3)
cur.close()
conn.close()
time.sleep(3)
exit()
```

I suggest the forum/group https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/pymysql-users for further discussion with the developer.